# twitter not displaying in internet explorer

Tags: twitter, sitefinity

My first post so please have mercy and/or kind suggestions.

I have a web application (Sitefinity CMS 3.7SP4) running in (c# .net 4.0) on IIS running on Server 2012. For the longest time, a single snippet of the code from Twitter displayed with no problems. Then on it's own, the code snippet appears not to turn the twitter link into the twitter feed.

By default, the twitter code snippet shows a shortcut to the twitter account. Upon the javascript running (sourced from twitter, so no code maintain) the feed displays the posts by latest.

This stopped working a few weeks ago on it's own. Not sure what it is as nothing appears to show up in the console (no errors, just a message 'navigation occured'. Also, the twitter displays in all other browsers.

I'll post my findings, but curious is anyone else had this happen recently and what was their findings.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Removing the following line from my sites template resolved the issue. Twitter feed now displays ok!

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />
```

Our organization has a requirement to use Internet Explorer 8. This was a few months ago and since then we added the use of Firefox. So I'll just go for an approval to remove this from our template (it's about time we either upgrade to a later version of IE or use Firefox as standard!!!)